# Can I run a shell script on OpenWrt from a remote host using OpenWISP2?

Tags: openwrt, openwisp

I am working on a hardware device running OpenWrt. I was wondering if I can manage my hardware and run shell scripts etc. remotely using OpenWisp2. Is it possible? If yes, then how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at the moment I'm writing.

You can only send configuration files, which can include scripts that can be also added to the crontab.

Sending commands will be possible once this branch is merged: https://github.com/openwisp/openwisp-controller/pull/31